# The images are not displayed when going up angular application to the server

Tags: angular, image, server

I am going up by my angular application to a remote server. I am up to the directory / public_html / Seacon, therefore I command the command as: NG Build --Prod - Base-Href = / Seacon. The problem is Q when the subway to the server The images are not seen. When I inspect the images I see the route I'm the way. ../../Assets/images / forg.log.gng because that is how I have it at local. The fasteners Assets try to move 2 directories outward (since this reference the image as well: ../../ [... Neither do the signs. What should I do to fix this problem? Thank you in advance to which I can help me, you thank it very much.

Comment: I'm afraid I'm not 100% sure I understand your question. Are you getting 404 errors from the browser trying and failing to load the images? If so, the failed request will give you clues as to how to fix the issue.

Comment: in the error console it does not show me error.  when I click on "inspect item" it says: "the image could not be loaded".

Comment: Did you check the network tab of your console?

Comment: it tells me error 301.

Comment: I know that the problem is in the reference to the image but I can not find the way to solve it. I tried to modify the address from the console, indicating the directory where the assets folder is located and it does not work for me. I previously resolved it by moving the assets folder...

Comment: It would appear that the 301 error is being thrown by your server. Your server needs to be configured to serve static assets from the folders you need them from. What kind of server are you running?

Comment: I am explaining my question, I do not understand why you send me to another forum.

Comment: it is a linux remote server. I explain: when I program my application locally, the assets folder I have outside the app folder, so when I want to use an image use ../../. The problem is when I upload it to the server. The assets folder should not I have outside the App folder when I program in local? I noticed that when I run the ng build command, the assets folder is created next to the other files in the same directory. This will be the problem? I moved the assets folder to the directory where I have the files of the page (this I did on the server) and some images load and others do not.

Answer (score 1):

## angular.json

```
 "assets": [
  "src/assets"    <====
 ],
```

Use image path as:-

```
src="assets/images/..."
```

Hard refresh the browser, clearing cache.

Comment: I must change the route of all the pictures then? They are enough. There will be some way of not making it manual?

Comment: I must change the route of all the pictures then? They are enough. There will be some way of not making it manual?

Comment: Just replace ../../Assets/images /  to  assets/images/ and check if its working.